# How can I structure a large query that encompasses multiple steps?

Tags: mysql

I have some data like this [(download 10,000 rows of sample data here)](https://easyupload.io/fzr3va):

```
id   parent sequence   mz1_monoisotopic 
---------------------------------------
1    0      SGVNHR     669.34           
2    0      IEEIATDLK  1030.99
3    0      AMDAWGAS   1030.07          
5    1      MDLILDDR   990.49
7    1      AAAGGGAG   1029.50           
8    1      LEVSEELIEK 1188.64
```

I need to perform a series of steps on it, and I am not sure how to structure my query. Here are the steps:

1. Expand this table. Look at the `sequence`, and count the number of `M`'s in each sequence. For every `M` in the sequence, create a new entry where the `mz1_monoisotopic` value is increased by 16. I achieved this with a recursive common table expression (**SEE CODE AT BOTTOM**)

   ```
   id   parent sequence   mz1_monoisotopic  <--- THIS IS THE EXPANDED TABLE
   ---------------------------------------
   1    0      SGVNHR     1006.34           
   2    0      IEEIATDLK  1030.99
   3    0      AMDAWGAS   1030.07
   4    0      AMDAWGAS   1046.07   <--- NEW ROW! mz1_monoisotopic increased by 16.       
   5    1      MDLILDDR   990.49
   6    1      MDLILDDR   1006.49   <--- NEW ROW, mz1_monoisotopic increased by 16.
   7    1      AAAGGGAG   1029.50           
   8    1      LEVSEELIEK 1188.64
   ```
2. Using a list of user-defined values (that can be variable in length) -- lets say `[1006, 1030, 1351 ...]`, search through this new expanded table (from step 1) and find rows where `mz1_monoisotopic` is within 1 unit of each value (`WHERE mz1_monoisotopic BETWEEN value - 1 AND value + 1`). Each value can match to multiple `parents` but may only return one match PER `parent`. So, the value `1030` is within 1 unit of rows 2, 3 and 7. Two of these are from `parent == 0`, so it must select the one with the lowest error. One of these is from `parent` 1, so it can keep it. Some expected output:

   ```
   #RESULT FROM QUERYING WITH 1006:

   id   parent sequence   mz1_monoisotopic 
   ---------------------------------------
   1    0      SGVNHR     1006.34 
   6    1      MDLILDDR   1006.49    

   #RESULT FROM QUERYING WITH 1030:

   id   parent sequence   mz1_monoisotopic 
   ---------------------------------------
   3    0      AMDAWGAS   1030.07
   7    1      AAAGGGAG   1029.50    

   ...
   ```
3. Combine the results of each of these separate queries into one table

   ```
    id   parent sequence   mz1_monoisotopic 
    ---------------------------------------
    1    0      SGVNHR     1006.34           
    3    0      AMDAWGAS   1030.07     
    6    1      MDLILDDR   1006.49   
    7    1      AAAGGGAG   1029.50
   ```

I don't know where to begin if I want to separately query with a list of numbers like an array, as I mentioned. I need help turning these into a larger, single query. Here is my CTE for step 1:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte (id, parent, sequence, mz1_monoisotopic, missed_cleavages, MSO) AS
(
  SELECT 
        id,
        parent,
        sequence, 
        (mz1_monoisotopic
            + ((CHAR_LENGTH(sequence) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE( sequence, 'C', ''))) * 57)
            # More fixed mods
        ) as mz1_monoisotopic,  
        missed_cleavages,
        0 AS MSO
  FROM 
        `1_plant_trypsin_dig` 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
        id,
        parent,
        sequence,
        `mz1_monoisotopic` + 15.999 AS `mz1_monoisotopic`,
        missed_cleavages,
        MSO + 1
  FROM 
        cte 
  WHERE 
        MSO < (CHAR_LENGTH(sequence) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE( sequence, 'M', '')))
)
```

And here is the query for selecting the row with the least error, grouped by `parent`:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    parent, 
    sequence, 
    mz1_monoisotopic,
    MIN(1101 - mz1_monoisotopic) AS err 
FROM 
    1_plant_trypsin_dig 
WHERE 
    mz1_monoisotopic 
BETWEEN 
    1100.251 - 1
AND
    1100.251 + 1
GROUP BY 
    parent;
```

Comment: ...there is no solution that does not require a helper table, just in case you're waiting for that. (unless you consider a nasty kludge with dynamically generated SQL a solution)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I accepted this answer a few days ago but it must have not gone through. Your solution works, but I don't understand the `ROW NUMBER` ... `PARTITION BY`... section, so I'll have to read up on that. Thank you very much!

Comment: The `OVER` clause defines a so-called window, see [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html). There are a couple of others besides `ROW_NUMBER()` , it's quite a useful feature. Run the inner query on its own (i.e. without the part that selects `WHERE rn = 1` ) to see what the `ROW_NUMBER()` does here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I'm not going into any details pertaining to expanding the table, as you seem to have managed that correctly on your own.

The second question can be solved with a search table and a partitioned `ROW_NUMBER()`.

When we assume the following base table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE 1_plant_trypsin_dig (
  id INT,
  parent INT,
  sequence VARCHAR(50),
  mz1_monoisotopic DECIMAL(10,2)
);
INSERT INTO 1_plant_trypsin_dig VALUES (1, 0, 'SGVNHR', 1006.34);
INSERT INTO 1_plant_trypsin_dig VALUES (2, 0, 'IEEIATDLK', 1030.99);
INSERT INTO 1_plant_trypsin_dig VALUES (3, 0, 'AMDAWGAS', 1030.07);
INSERT INTO 1_plant_trypsin_dig VALUES (4, 0, 'AMDAWGAS', 1046.07);
INSERT INTO 1_plant_trypsin_dig VALUES (5, 1, 'MDLILDDR', 990.49);
INSERT INTO 1_plant_trypsin_dig VALUES (6, 1, 'MDLILDDR', 1006.49);
INSERT INTO 1_plant_trypsin_dig VALUES (7, 1, 'AAAGGGAG', 1029.50);
INSERT INTO 1_plant_trypsin_dig VALUES (8, 1, 'LEVSEELIEK', 1188.64);
```

and a search table like this (this could be a connection-specific temporary table, to support a multi-user scenario):

```
CREATE TABLE search (
  mz1_monoisotopic DECIMAL(10,2)
);
INSERT INTO search VALUES (1006.00);
INSERT INTO search VALUES (1030.00);
```

then - assuming we define "error" as the absolute difference between the actual `mz1_monoisotopic` and the searched `mz1_monoisotopic` - we can do this:

```
SELECT id, parent, sequence, mz1_monoisotopic, err FROM (
  SELECT 
    d.id,
    d.parent,
    d.sequence,
    d.mz1_monoisotopic,
    ABS(d.mz1_monoisotopic - s.mz1_monoisotopic) err,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (
      PARTITION BY s.mz1_monoisotopic, d.parent
      ORDER BY ABS(d.mz1_monoisotopic - s.mz1_monoisotopic), id
    ) rn
  FROM
    1_plant_trypsin_dig d
    INNER JOIN search s ON
      d.mz1_monoisotopic BETWEEN s.mz1_monoisotopic - 1 AND s.mz1_monoisotopic + 1
) result WHERE rn = 1;
```

and receive this result:

```
id    parent   sequence    mz1_monoisotopic   err
1     0        SGVNHR      1006.34            0.34
6     1        MDLILDDR    1006.49            0.49
3     0        AMDAWGAS    1030.07            0.07
7     1        AAAGGGAG    1029.50            0.50
```

Remember that you need to define tie-breaker for the `ROW_NUMBER()` order, in case two rows have the same error value. I've used `id`, your preference might be different.

See live example at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75738999738d10b03e43fb768267eefc